# partial fraction decomposition third power

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I would like to use partial fraction decomposition on: $\frac{x+1}{x^4+x}$. The denominator can be broken into $x(x^3+1)$. I'm just not sure how to deal with the $x^3+1$ part. Do I put something like: $Ax^2+Bx+C$ on top? That would lead to a step looking like this: $\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{x^3+1}+\frac{D}{x}$. Or, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: $x^3+1$ is divisible by $x-1$

Comment: @TitoEliatron, I think you meant $x+1$.

Comment: Yeah, it was a misprint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{x+1}{x^4+x}=\frac{x+1}{x(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{1}{x(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x+1}{x^2-x+1}
$$